# Git statistics API JSON

Tags: json, git

I want to get the number of commits per day per hour. With the following command, I am able to get the output in json format. However, I would like to know if I can add the key to the values in json format using command line?

```
curl https://api.github.com/repos/test/myrepo/stats/punch_card
```

Current output:

```
[
    0,
    2,
    32
]
```

Expected output:

```
[
    day: 0,
    hour: 2,
    commits: 32
]
```

Comment: As far as the [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/statistics/) docs say, the API doesn't emit keys along with those values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't specified anything beyond "command line", I'm assuming you want a `bash`-based solution. This simple (though kind of ugly) script will do what you want, while maintaining indentation (apart from the closing square bracket of the overall response):

```
#!/bin/bash

resp=$(curl https://api.github.com/repos/test/myrepo/stats/punch_card)

nextPref=""
for val in $resp
do
    echo "$nextPref $val"
    if [[ $val == "[" && $nextPref == "" ]]
    then
        nextPref="      "
    elif [[ $val == "[" && $nextPref == "   " ]]
    then
        nextPref="              day:"
    elif [[ $nextPref == "          day:" ]]
    then
        nextPref="              hour:"
    elif [[ $nextPref == "          hour:" ]]
    then
        nextPref="              commits:"
    elif [[ $nextPref == "          commits:" ]]
    then
        nextPref="      "
    fi
done
```